# Layout - Windows 10 mobile - unnecessary stripe

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-mobile, uwp-xaml

I have one problem with layout when I running my Windows Universal App on Nokia Lumia 635. It is unnecessary stripe which showed up recently. I really don't know if I changed something, but before it was alright. In emulator stripe is black. On my device is white.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: your xaml code might help. on the last one it look like it is the status bar, although i'm not sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It is unnecessary stripe which showed up recently.

It seems like the stripe is for status bar. [Hide the status bar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.statusbar.hideasync) like follows may resolve your issue.

```
public RemoveGap()
{
   this.InitializeComponent(); 
   if (ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar"))
   {
       StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().HideAsync();  
   }
}
```

Pay attention, to use this class, we need to add a mobile special reference as following picture shows:[image]

> I really don't know if I changed something, but before it was alright.

I guess you just change the target platform, e.g. you tested it on a pc device before or some other device which doesn't have status bar.